# Are we crazy to use node.js for a long running high performance server process with a lot of in memory state?

Tags: node.js, performance, server, reliability, stream-processing

I work for company X, we've committed, for now, to using node.js (with a type checker) for most backend systems for a bunch of pretty good reasons. We are in the process of fleshing out some pretty complicated and pretty mission-critical streaming processing style jobs, and some workflow management stuff, etc.

Some of this is leaning on patterns like replicated state machine, with state being built as events arrive. Strict consistency, ordering is required so the code is kind of touchy. Additionally a fair bit of state hangs around in memory for ~minutes. Ultra high performance is not critical, but reliability is.

I come from a jvm background. I would be more comfortable with sophisticated debugging and analysis tools like yourkit, static typing, a more tuneable garbage collector, etc., rock solid built in sdk etc.

Is it crazy to stand up complicated mission-critical infra with node? My gut tells me its a fairly decent platform as far as it goes, that architecture / design will determine reliability as always, and that skepticism tends to reflect more of non type-checked, pre-es6 idea of node than what people (can) use today. Is lack of detailed tunability for the garbage collector a big problem?

Comment: For type-checking, you can use TypeScript with node.js. Your gut that architecture and design (not the choice of run-time environment) will determine reliability is pretty much true.  State hanging around in memory for minutes is not an issue.  Can't really say whether GC tunability is something that would matter.  That's not usually an issue with node.js.

Comment: The bigger architectural difference between node.js and jvm is the existence of threads in the jvm.  While most concurrency issues either just work fine with proper asynchronous I/O design in node.js or can be solved by using the node.js clustering or moving some CPU intensive operations to another process, node.js by its nature doesn't multi-task multiple CPU-intensive operations.  It scales lots of I/O really well (probably better than jvm).

Comment: The process of designing/coding with asynchronous takes some learning in node.js (if not learned in a previous language), but is ultimately not subject to the kinds of reliability/concurrency challenges that a design with multiple threads and mutexes can sometimes be subject to with imperfect design because of its single threaded nature.  In a larger team, I think it's probably easier to code for high reliability in node.js because it just isn't subject to some of the hard-to-test-for things you have to worry about with multiple threads.

Comment: Re. typechecker, we're using flow. Typechecker is essential. Comment re. GC worries me a bit. I dont see how GC could magically not be a problem in a garbage collected language. Suspect if thats true its because people arent building complicated high scale stuff. Re. threads/concurrency, I agree. This is a big benefit its truly single threaded and it eliminates several entire classes of bugs/perf and functional. Our work is mostly io dispatch as a result. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: What kind of garbage collector tunability do you think is important?  Why do you think that is needed?